# Richfaces true pagination - range always 0 and -1

Tags: ajax, pagination, richfaces

I'm trying to make true pagination in a `rich:extendedDataTable` having:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable
                        value="#{genServOrderManagerBean.orchestrationServiceVOs}"
                        var="service" first="#{genServOrderManagerBean.currentPage}"
                        id="orchestrationServicesTable"
                        noDataLabel="#{bsmPortalMessage['message.common.extendedTable.noDataLabel']}"
                        style="height:100%;width:700px" filterVar="filterValue"
                        sortMode="single" styleClass="stable" selectionMode="single"
                        selection="#{genServOrderManagerBean.selection}" rows="10"
                        clientRows="10"
                        rowKeyVar="row">


                        <a4j:ajax execute="@this" event="selectionchange"
                            listener="#{genServOrderManagerBean.selectionListener}"
                            render="orderInformation,serviceDetails" />
```

......(some columns over here)......

```
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <rich:dataScroller page="#{genServOrderManagerBean.currentPage}"/>
                </f:facet>

            </rich:extendedDataTable>
```

The problem is that in my walk() method range is always firstRow=0,rows=-1 and so it gets everything from database, instead of getting only 10 rows at a time.
Can someone help, please?

Comment: Use pagination with `rich:dataTable` not with `rich:extendedDataTable`. Extended data table was designed for different purpose (with different behavior).

Comment: I changed it to `rich:dataTable` and I had to change `ajax event="rowclick"`. Now it still gets everything from database (firstRow=0, rows=-1) and if I click on a row, nothing happens. Previously, if I clicked a row, a new panel would appear below.

Comment: rich:dataScroller is meant to take the datamodel and split it into pages, if you want to retrieve new data every time you change a page you'll have to implement custom scrolling.

Comment: Ok. I'm pretty new with richfaces so could you please give me an example? (a link or something). Thank you.

Comment: Example of data model is not a few line of code. Check [richfaces showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org)

Comment: I never said it's a few lines, or that I need a few lines. Being at my first project with richfaces I asked if someone could help with this problem or a link to an example, no matter how big it is. Thank you,